# Is there a way to visualize music from the microphone?

Tags: audio, music

With all the media and 3D graphics capabilities available on modern hardware I'd like to see a nice visualisation application that listens to the microphone.

If anyone knows the [G-Force](http://www.soundspectrum.com/) winamp plugin they know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Some 3rd-party apps can do this, such as:

- [Spectral Audio Analyzer](https://market.android.com/details?id=radonsoft.net.spectralview)

  > Free real-time audio analyser with 8 kHz spectral bandwidth. Display any sort of audio from the microphone as a coloured spectrogram. Identify environmental noise, search for annoying tones, view harmonic patterns of instruments and voices, analyse the frequency range of your speaker... .

Comment: Ah thanks very much, I hadn't found those. The AudioScope one is getting there but none are anything close to G-Force or Milkdrop or anything like that. I'm sure given time something will appear in the market. These are still handy analysers though!